# GraniteDS plugin / modular architecture

Tags: java, spring, apache-flex, modularity, graniteds

My goal is to create an AIR/GraniteDS (Tide/Spring/Hibernate) application with ability to extend it by third party developers using flex modules on client-side and some "modular" technology on server-side.

For flex side, GraniteDS gives possibility to add modules into Tide context. 
But i have not any idea what is going to be happening on server side.

What do i have to use on server side? Any modular framework which will works with GraniteDS?

Will be grateful for any help, ideas or point to sample code or tutorial.

Comment: I can't see a question here.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question.

Comment: I have been reading about Gemini Blueprint, but it looks too complicated for me.

What about **impala** framework? https://code.google.com/p/impala/

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is quite general. The answer would be - You don't have to use anything particlar, GraniteDS will work with just anything. You can build your server in Spring, EJB, or anything else. GraniteDS is here really like a "plugin" as you said which will than serve for transfering data to your flex client. In flex, graniteDS will also take care of your data, but it can also be used as client framweork, but it is optional, and as said, it's CLIENT framework only.
Just create your server independent from client side I would recommend.